# React app on gh-pages : can not link to local files

Tags: html, reactjs, href, github-pages

If I create a react app, and in this app there's a link to a local html file, once this app published on gh-pages, for some reasons said link doesn't lead anywhere, it just redirect the user on the same page he was in before clicking the link .

For exemple:

If I create a simple app with CRA like so :

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        I'm the homepage
        <a id='testlink' href='html2.html'> Go to the second page </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And in the public folder I create a new html file "html2.html" that simply says

```
I am the second app !
```

And that's all, a simple app supposed to jump from index.html to html2.html when a link is clicked. Well this app works fine when tested with `npm start`, it works fine if launched via the static html file provided with `npm run build`, but when deployed on gh-pages, suddendly the link does not lead anywhere.

[Here is the app described above deployed on ghpages](https://hadrienallemon.github.io/ghapp/html2.html)

One workaround this problem would be to upload all the apps separately on gh-pages, or to use react router, but I wanted to know if I was just missing something. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

On [React](https://reactjs.org) projects you should use [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) to handle `routes` and change pages.

Simple example:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <hr />

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
);

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
);

const Topics = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Topics</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>Rendering with React</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>Components</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>Props v. State</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic} />
    <Route
      exact
      path={match.url}
      render={() => <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>}
    />
  </div>
);

const Topic = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
  </div>
);

export default BasicExample;
```

Comment: Even to redirect to a vanilla html file react router is required ? And is it normal that it works without react router when tested locally but not once hosted ?

Comment: @Hallemon Yes, it's required on SPA projects. and it's normal when it doesn't work on the real host.